# Unable to deserialize entity which contains field with type org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, java, path

I have an `Entity` which has a field named `coordinates` of type `org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath` :

```
public class Geometry
{
 ...

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private PGpath coordinates;
```

I am trying to build a `JSONObject` with some of these entities but I am getting the message:

```
could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Whatever your join column name is in your PGpath class")
private PGpath coordinates;
```

PGpath will also be an @Entity class with its own columns and column constraints, such as:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "Column name", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String myPrimaryKey;
```